# Setting up ETH ethernet on a custom carrier with TQMa6UL2-AA

Tags: yocto, ethernet, imx6

I'm setting up a custom carrier board made in my company with one TQMa6UL2-AA i.MX6UL based on evaluation board of TQ stka6ul. I already have a booteable image with u-boot and linux generated with Yocto-Project and TQ BSP. I'm traying to set-up the two ethernet interfaces,

In u-boot I could see the interfaces:

```
=> mii info
PHY 0x00: OUI = 0x01F0, Model = 0x0F, Rev = 0x01, 100baseT, FDX
PHY 0x01: OUI = 0x01F0, Model = 0x0F, Rev = 0x01, 100baseT, FDX
```

And, if I config the IP address, I could make a ping to one computer, so I think the hardware is working,however, in Linux I couldn't see nothing. I don't know how I could fix this problem, I suppose the Linux kernel can't recognize the PHY but I don't know why.

Could anyone help with my problem?

Regards,

Comment: what do you get when you type ifconfig in cli?

Comment: When i execute ifconfig i only see the information about the loopback interface ```root@tqma6ulx-mba6ulx:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```